# getting the previous year of a varchar data type

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a query

```
SELECT * from table1 where sy='$school_year';
```

And my

```
 $school_year='2013-2014'      //which is a varchar
```

How can I make

```
 $school_year='2012-2013'
```

I've tried

```
 SELECT * from table1 where  sy='$school_year'-1;
```

but gives me an error stating that $school_year is not an integer. How can I get the previous $school_year? or is it possible?

Comment: If you have control of the database design, consider changing this field to just contain the beginning or ending year of the school term. Life then gets much easier, and not just with this particular question.

Comment: I agree with what Jonathan said.. restructuring your table would be better and a lot easier to do queries on future. try breaking the string into two columns, and concat it when you want.. :)

id, from_year, to_year
1, 2013, 2014

CONCAT_WS('-', from_year, to_year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can do something like this: Consider this example:

```
$school_year='2013-2014';
$school_year = explode('-', $school_year);
$school_year[0] = ((int) $school_year[0] - 1);
$school_year[1] = ((int) $school_year[1] - 1);
$school_year = implode('-', $school_year);

$statement = "SELECT * from table1 where  sy='$school_year';";
echo $statement;

// Sample
// SELECT * from table1 where sy='2012-2013';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get the immediately preceding value:

```
select *
from table1
where sy < '$school_year'
order by sy desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$year = '2013-2014';

$prev_year = substr($year, 0, 4);
$prev_year = ($prev_year-1) . '-' . $prev_year;

$q = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE sy='$prev_year'";
```

`$q` will be

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE sy='2012-2013'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider restructuring your table. Your possible options (instead of the `'2013-2014'` formatted `varchar`) are:

- Use the starting (or ending) year as `int` (most easy, least error prone)
- Use one of the available [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html), possibly `int4range` (or [create your own](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html)), and [create `+` & `-` operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createoperator.html) for them (9.2+).
- [Create your own type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html), with your own representation format, and [create `+` & `-` operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createoperator.html) for them.